# AWS Pinpoint: Set APNS "mutable-content": 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, aws-pinpoint

AWS Poinpoint APNS by default sets `"mutable-content": 0`.

I am using Node.js.

Below works fine, but `mutable-content` is always `0`. `"mutable-content": 0`:

```
var messageRequest = {
'Addresses': {
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/: {
'ChannelType': channelType
}
},
'MessageConfiguration': {
'APNSMessage': {
'Action': action,
'Body': message,
'Priority': priority,
'SilentPush': silent,
'Title': title,
'TimeToLive': ttl,
'Url': url,
}
}
```

Below is the `payload` I get when an APNS is sent using the above setup

```
["aps": {
alert = {
body = "TEST";
title = "Test message sent from Amazon Pinpoint.";
};
"content-available" = 1;
"mutable-content" = 0;
}, "data": {
pinpoint = {
deeplink = "https://www.example.com";
};
}]
```

How can I set `"mutable-content": 1` for an APNS through AWS Pinpoint?

Comment: Having same issue.  Did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation but this worked for me after some trial and error:

```
var payload = {
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Bold text in the notification",
            "body": "Second line in the notification"
        },
        "sound": "default",
        "mutable-content": 1
    }
};

var messageRequest = {
    Addresses: {
        [token]: {
            ChannelType: "APNS",
        },
    },
    MessageConfiguration: {
        APNSMessage: {
            RawContent: JSON.stringify(payload),
        },
    },
};
```

Just replace their template with RawContent and create the payload as you would normally.  Can refer to apple docs on how to create the raw payload.  You can also adjust content-available key using this method.  Here is the link to how to create a payload with json:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but just ran into this issue and wanted to share my solution.

I found that setting the "MediaUrl" parameter to a non-empty string would cause pinpoint to send "mutable-content": 1

I did not see this in any of the pinpoint documentation.